# Is common control 6 supported in MBCS applications?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MBCS (multibyte characters) MFC application, I have removed `#ifdefs` from `stdafx.h` file and now my MBCS  app uses common control 6.
in internet I have found many articls where users said that some of common control 6 controls have problems in MBCS apps (`CMFCLinkControl` `CListView` `CMFCButton`...)
but I could't find some microsoft article that common control 6 is not supported in MBCS  application, or the list of contols that have problems with non Unicode app, is there any article by microsoft ?

Comment: if supported then there is some bugs, see  this [topic](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794158/cmfclinkctrl-on-dialog-causes-heap-corruption-in-multi-byte-character-set-apps), I have the same problem with CMFCButton control,  also [this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where I have found this ->Note  ComCtl32.dll version 6 is Unicode only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for MBCS in ComCtl32.dll version 6. MBCS applications mostly still work due to a [compatibility loophole](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081106-00/?p=20303). If you cannot convert your application to Unicode, use version 5.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you intend to support Windows 98, or Windows ME - and that is not a suggestion - my advice is this:

- Build the next version of your application as a UNICODE application.
- Put all your effort there.
- Put none of your effort into fixing MBCS
  issues.

Nobody should be writing a new application for windows except in Unicode. Not since Windows ME and Windows98 went end-of-life.

Comment: My app uses some non UNICODE libraries , and there is no need to change them to Unicode, and now what I need to do , convert char to wchar in my app and use it and convert back for working with existing libraries? I think its not very good idea.

Comment: @ArtashesBudaghyan, you know your application best. If you have a lot of external dependencies, especially if you don't have source code, then you are probably right.